# Call multiple node forms using multiform_get_form()

Tags: nodes

I am trying to call multiple node forms using multiform_get_form() a utility function by multiform module.Here is the code I am trying with

```
function custom_multiform_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['add/multiform'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add Spread',
    'page callback' => 'multiform_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array(array('article_node_form'), array('page_node_form')),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

I am not seeing any node fields on page add/multiform

Answer (score 0):

Use your own 'page callback', and in this callback call `module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');` which is required for node forms